# Building Wireshark LDAP filter for future scripting

Tags: ldap, wireshark

all

On our environment we have several servers still using ldap for authentication and I need to filter ldap requests for 8 hours to have an overview on how many different accounts we may have exposed.

The issue is I cannot create captures that are too large. (Just for an example, using a filter to ldap port and marking the flags of a TCP request I barely can capture 3 minutes before my capture is hitting 100MB).

I wonder if there is a way to build a capture filter that would look for a HEX on the DATA part of the packet.

Does anyone have any clue on how I would be able to do that?

Currently I am using a capture filter like:

```
port 389 && tcp[13] == 24
```

and a display filter like:

```
ldap.bindRequest_element && ldap.messageID==1
```

Another issue is that doing this I couldn't come up with a script that would strip the username so I could inform all possibly compromised users to change their PWDs.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this.
Just for people that are still curious or would need something similar I used the following:

```
port 389 && tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2) + 2:2] = 0x0201 && tcp[((tcp[12:1] & 0xf0) >> 2) + 4:1] = 0x01
```

This check the data part of the packet and since some of the bytes are always in the same position and are all the same for a ldap bind request with message id 1 I used that to build the filter.

Cheers.